# I can't go to another activity, from createfood to displayfood

Tags: android

```java
if (awesomeValidation.validate() && imageView2.getDrawable() != null) {
  Toast.makeText(CreateFood.this, "Food Successfully Added !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
  Drawable drawable = imageView2.getDrawable();
  Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
  byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
  String image_str = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

  backgroundWorker.execute(type,
    etFoodName.getText().toString(),
    etDescription.getText().toString(),
    etPrice.getText().toString(),
    listFoodType.getSelectedItem().toString(),
    listCategory.getSelectedItem().toString(),
    listStatus.getSelectedItem().toString(),
    image_str);

  String foodName = etFoodName.getText().toString();
  String foodDescription = etDescription.getText().toString();
  String foodType = listFoodType.getSelectedItem().toString();
  String foodCate = listCategory.getSelectedItem().toString();
  String foodStatus = listStatus.getSelectedItem().toString();
  String foodPrice = etPrice.getText().toString();

  Intent intent = new Intent(CreateFood.this, DisplayFood.class);

  intent.putExtra("FoodName", foodName);
  intent.putExtra("FoodDescription", foodDescription);
  intent.putExtra("FoodType", foodType);
  intent.putExtra("FoodPrice", foodPrice);
  intent.putExtra("FoodCate", foodCate);
  intent.putExtra("FoodStatus", foodStatus);
  intent.putExtra("picture", b);

  startActivity(intent);

  break;
} else {
  Toast.makeText(CreateFood.this, "Invalid Input !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

I can't go to another activity, from CreateFood to DisplayFood. After I click Create Button, this activity will refresh and back go my Main Activity.

Comment: any error ?if yes post here...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
CreateFood.this.startActivity(intent);
```